# break from while loop from anonymous function

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js

I am new to javascript, my background is python and ruby and I am having issues dealing with javascript anonymous functions, my problem is the following:

I have an element in the page which has an attribute value (true/false), I need to keep performing an action until this attribute changes value.

the code that I tried out is below, as you could guess, the `break` won't quit the loop if `result.value == true`... Any idea if I am in the right direction?

```
var counter = 0;
while (counter < 5) {
  this
    .click('#someelementid')
  counter++;
  this
    .getAttribute('#someelementid', 'disabled', function(result) {
      if (result.value == 'true') {
        this.break;
      }
    }.bind(this));
  this.api.pause(1000);
};
```

My assumption is that by binding this, I have access to the while block? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried changing your code to something like below ?

```
var counter = 0;
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
while (counter < 5) {
  arr.forEach(
    (element) => {
      if (counter < 5) { // if you don't have this it will print all 5, else it prints only 3
        console.log('Element value:', element);
      }
      if (element == 3) {
        counter = 5;
      }
    }
  );
}
```

What happens is this:

When you enter the `while` loop it will enter the `forEach` loop and start iterating, when it reaches `element == 3` it will set `counter` to `5`, but it still has to finish the current `forEach` loop, once it does it wont perform another `while` loop therefore exiting it.

So changing your code to:

```
var counter = 0;
while (counter < 5) {
  this
    .click('#someelementid')
  counter++;
  this
    .getAttribute('#someelementid', 'disabled', function(result) {
      if (result.value == 'true') {
        counter = 5; // This should do the trick (without 'this')
      }
    }.bind(this));
  this.api.pause(1000);
};
```

Comment: I have, although even after setting counter to 5, it doesn't seem to break... not sure why..

Comment: I've edited the answer with solution that works for me, try to implement it please.

Comment: cool, I've managed to get it working, thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The break inside a function would not break the loop outside the function.

Through getAttribute() get the result inline instead of having a callback. then you can break the function.

Or

Have a global variable. `breakLoop = false;` set it to true; inside the callback function. And put a check on this variable in the while loop. `while(!breakLoop ..)`

Another approach.

Don't have a loop altogether.

```
var counter = 0;

function doSomething(){
    this.click('#someelementid');
    counter++;

    this.getAttribute('#someelementid', 'disabled', function(result) {
        if(result.value != 'true' && counter<5){
            this.api.pause(1000);
            doSomething();
        }
    }.bind(this);

};
```

Comment: would it be possible to give an example of how to get the result inline instead of having a callback? trying to figure out by my own but would be helpful if you could send me to the right direction

Comment: I think the framework you are using nightwatch does not support such inline api. You can try the second option by using a global variable to break the loop.